# jquery read php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

im trying to change one var to get and stuck

here is what I did:

```
var choices = [['Australia', 'au'], ['Austria', 'at'], ['Brasil', 'br']];
```

so this is working, and I want to change it on

```
$.getJSON('/modules/profile/readCountry.php',function(data){
    arrays = data;
});
var choices = arrays;
```

but is not working

the php file is:

```
foreach($countryies as $countr => $countrv) {
    $json[] = array($countrv,$countr);
}
header("Content-type:application/json"); 
$out = array_values($json);
echo json_encode($out);
```

and output is:

```
[['Australia', 'au'], ['Austria', 'at'], ['Brasil', 'br']]
```

how to fine out what is missing or is not working ?

Comment: You have missed a closing ' in the $.getJSON function. Is that just in the question, or is it missing in your code?

Comment: just in question

Comment: why getJson ? Can't u use just $.get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getJSON is async call

```
    var choices = [];
    $.getJSON('/modules/profile/readCountry.php',function(data){
        choices = data;
        // do something with array
    });
```